# cannot see files from SSHFS

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, sshfs

I followed the instructions provided by [digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh) to mount an SSH connection using sshfs and macfuse. It is working from the commandline I can see the remote folders in /mnt/mydir

But in Finder the /mnt/ folder appears totally empty.

I think this is a file permissions issue, as the directory inside is `rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  4096 16 Jul  2013 mydir`.

But I'm not sure who I should give it to in order to see it. I tried running `chown username:staff /mnt/mydir` but it didn't seem to have an effect. Also I don't want to mess up any permissions on the mount, so I'm kinda not wanting to do anything recursively.

Or is this not meant for use from within Finder?